Multi-layer glass vs polycarbonate windshields?
I've been researching the history of airline windows and windshields.
Windshields seem to be made out of two types of material. Either multi-layer composite glass or polycarbonate.
I'm wondering what material is more popular on commercial airlines, and has window technology changed over the past 50 or so years on jumbo jets?

Welcome to [aviation.se], please take the [tour]. This place works best on a one question per post basis. While your two questions are related for you, they will get entirely different answers. Please [edit] to ask one question, then feel free to ask the other as a completely separate question.

Not polycarbonate.  Acrylic.  PC is too soft, can't tolerate exposure to gasoline and certain solvents, and scratches if you look at it with a mean face. Windshields are mostly laminated glass, mostly for the hardness, tho some do use acrylic windshields, Pax windows are acrylic (plexiglas). A 1/4 inch thick acrylic pax window has about the same tensile strength as the surrounding ".040 skin.

See also FAA AC 25.775-1 about windows and windshields.
